# Textbox over a gradient in reportlab/python

Tags: python, reportlab

I have a following piece of code in reportlab/python:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, landscape
from reportlab.lib.colors import red, yellow, green
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
from reportlab.lib import colors

c = canvas.Canvas("hello.pdf", pagesize=landscape(A4))

c.linearGradient(105*mm, 200*mm, 180*mm, 100*mm, (red, yellow))


textobject = c.beginText()
# Set text location (x, y)
textobject.setTextOrigin(10, 730)
# Set font face and size
textobject.setFont('Times-Roman', 40)
# Write a line of text + carriage return
textobject.textLine(text='ABC')
# Change text color
textobject.setFillColor(colors.white)
# Write red text
textobject.textLine(text='DEF')
# Write text to the canvas
c.drawText(textobject)

c.showPage()
c.save()
```

But the textlines are not visible.
Can you help me out.

I want to middle the text along the width and height.

How to add text within a rectangular textbox with rounded corners in reportlab.